# Can "Chauvinists" and "elitist" be same?

Tags: meaning

I was going through GRE vocabulary on magoosh app and it is stated that both have same meaning but clearly

> Chauvinist : a person displaying aggressive or exaggerated patriotism.

And

> Elitist: relating to or supporting the view that a society or system should be led by an elite.

which doesn't feel same to me.

Can someone please clarify?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*chauvinist* has a secondary meaning that has become more common in recent years:

> a person displaying excessive or prejudiced loyalty of support for a particular cause, group, or gender.

The most well known example of this is "male chauvinist".

This is the sense that is very similar to elitist, because the chauvinist typically believes that their group is the elite group, and should be in charge of society.